# Invoke iOS app at specific time and date

Tags: ios

I want my iOS app to know when a specific date and time arrives without any failure. Now this time can be in days/weeks/months and my application can be in backgorund Or in terminated state.

So there are following options:
a. Local notification -- but it doesn't notify when my app is in background.
b. Silent Push notification -- it will work but it requires us to built server for same.

Is there any other option with which we can achieve same?

Comment: you can schedule a Local Notification on a specific time. That will notify user even when app is terminated or in background.

Comment: There is no absolutely guaranteed way that you can achieve this.  The best you can do is a silent push from a server at the specified time, but the device could be turned off or not have an active connection.

Comment: Why do you say a local notification doesn't notify when the app is in the background? It does, look at the [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UILocalNotification) class reference. The user will get a system alert/badge/alert sound (depending on what he sets in the preferences) when the app is not foreground.

Comment: @dirkgroten
I tried UILocalNotificaiton but it only notifies application in background when user click on notification message action.

Comment: ah, you actually want the app to be launched at the exact right time. That wasn't entirely clear from your question. Wondering what's your use case. Anyway, the answer below is correct, it cannot be done unless you're a VOIP app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way you can achieve this,
Your options are : 
1) By using **local notification** like schedule notification on particular time and store that time and related activity in userdefaults. whenever app state changes to background to foreground in appdelegates **- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application** method write a code to handle desired functionality.

2) Silent **push notification,** which works only when your app is in background/minimized state. Once your app is Killed(swipe up from multitasking), even silent push notification cannot wake up your app.

3) To overcome the limitations of silent push notifications, Apple introduced **Pushkit Notifications** in iOS8, for voip apps like whatsapp, Skype, etc, in which push kit notification once received, wakes up your app even it is terminated or not running in background. Again you cannot use Pushkit unless you are actually using voip.

Comment: "even silent push notification cannot wake up your app." Yes they do, an app that receives a silent push notification can perform some background activity after receiving it.The problem with silent pushes however is the time of their delivery can be delayed by several hours.

Comment: you are right @PotassiumPermanganate, but when app is killed (by swipe up in multitasking as i have mentioned) or its not running/terminated, except push kit notifications (no notification can wake your app.)

Answer (score 0):

No. Sounds like you have to use push notifications.

This is the only thing that would work if your app is terminated.