# How to reset Bool value everyday at midnight

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want a Bool value that turns to true every day at midnight does anyone know how I could achieve that. This is the code I've tried so far. I keep getting these errors:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'"

and

> generic struct 'ObservedObject' requires that 'ContentView.Daily' conform to 'ObservableObject'

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    class Daily: ObservableObject {
        @Published var timedbool: Bool = false
        private var timer: Timer?
        
        init(){
            scheduleDailyReset()
        }
        private func scheduleDailyReset(){
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            if let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())) {
                let timeInterval = tomorrow.timeIntervalSinceNow
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(setBool), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }
        
        @objc func setBool() {
            timedbool = true
            scheduleDailyReset()
        }
        func getBool() -> Bool {
            return timedbool
        }
        }
    
    @State var daily = Daily()
    @State var dailyreset: Bool = daily.getBool()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                if dailyreset{
                    navig2 = true
                }
```

I tried to make a class with a function to do the daily reset and then another function to return the reset bool value but it won't conform to View.

Comment: The code you posted might be correct, it's hard to say. The main question here is how do you ensure it's executed? You need your app to be running, or awaken to perform a background task. SO has plenty or relevant information that should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420586/ios-do-scheduled-operation-in-background-or-when-app-active, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75133787/how-to-wake-up-an-app-at-a-specific-time-in-ios, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609658/swift-background-execution-at-certain-time-each-morning...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545717/invoke-ios-app-at-specific-time-and-date, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217182/how-to-perform-a-background-task-at-a-given-date-on-ios...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timer is fine.

There are several problems in your code:

1. Move `class Daily` code to top-level. This will remove the `@ObservableObject` error.
2. Change `@State var daily` to `@StateObject`. This will make `@ObservableObject` update properly.
3. Don't use the function `getBool()` with `@State`. Use `@Published var timedbool` directly like `daily.timedbool`.
4. In the line of body `navig2 = true`, you are returning a Bool where you should return a View. You need to put a view here.

These would be my changes:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class Daily: ObservableObject {
    @Published var timedbool: Bool = false
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    init() {
        scheduleDailyReset()
    }
    private func scheduleDailyReset() {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        guard let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: calendar.startOfDay(for: .now)) else {
//        guard let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: 5, to: .now) else { // use this instead to test
            print("There's no tomorrow.")
            return
        }
        
        let timeInterval = tomorrow.timeIntervalSinceNow
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(setBool), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        print("timer: \(timer?.fireDate)")
    }
    
    @objc func setBool() {
        timedbool = true
        scheduleDailyReset()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var daily = Daily()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Confirm") {
                daily.timedbool = false  // set @Published var
            }
            .disabled(!daily.timedbool) // use @Published var
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: daily.timedbool) { bool in // use @Published var
            print("timed bool set to \(bool)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the view with a button is just an example of how to get and set `timedbool` in the view.

There's an alternate fireDate definition so you don't to stay up all night to see if this works.

I'd prefer to unwrap the optional `Date` with a `guard` statement here to avoid the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are a couple of issues with your code:

1. Use `@StateObject` instead of `@State` for `daily`, because it is an observable object, not a struct.
2. You cannot put non view-yielding swift code inside your body function like that. If you want to do some calculations put them inside a `onAppear` or `onChange(of:)` view modifier or similar according to your needs.

But the actual issue is that you need to schedule a background task in order to run code while the app likely is not running, in your case at midnight.
Here is a pointer to the relevant documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks

As a last note:
I suggest you review your requirement, do you really need run the code at that time or would it be sufficient to reevaluate if it is a new day once the app got launched again by the user, which would be much simpler.

Comment: Wouldn't a timer missed due to inactivity fire next time the app is activated?

Comment: Why would you need a timer at all? Maybe it is sufficient to store the last time the app was opened and compare against that on next open to see if a day has passed.

Comment: I totally agree to your suggestion to reconsider other options than a timer.