# Re-enable button based on date in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, date, button, swiftui, modifier

I'm in the process of building a habit tracker and I've come across a problem. In my app there is a button that you can click to indicate that you have completed your task. As soon as this button is pressed, I set it to .disabled() so that the task cannot be executed more than once. Now I want the button to be able to be pressed again every day. How can I ensure that the button is enabled again at 0 o'clock? I have tried to change the variable isButtonDisabled at 0:00, but without success. Any help is appreciated!

```
import SwiftUI

struct HabitButton: View {
    @State private var isButtonDisabled: Bool = false // This value should change every new day at 0 o'clock.
    @AppStorage("streak") private var streak: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        if (isButtonDisabled == false) {
            Button {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0)
                isButtonDisabled = true
            } label: {
                Text("I have eaten an apple")
                    .padding(.vertical, 20)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .fontDesign(.rounded)
                    .bold()
                    .frame(width: 400)
            }
            .background(BasicColor.tint)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        } else {
            Button {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(0)
                isButtonDisabled = true
            } label: {
                Text("I have eaten an apple")
                    .padding(.vertical, 20)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .fontDesign(.rounded)
                    .bold()
                    .frame(width: 400)
            }
            .background(BasicColor.tint)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            .disabled(true)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    HabitButton()
}
```

I tried something similar to that, but these expressions are not allowed in SwiftUI.

```
struct HabitButton: View {
    @State private var isButtonDisabled: Bool = false // This value should change every new day at 0 o'clock.
    @AppStorage("streak") private var streak: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        if (Date() == 0) {
            isButtonDisabled = false
        }
```

Comment: So, you need to know the last time the button was actioned (or if it has been actioned).  Also, remember `Date` is a representation of date AND time. If the current date (without time) is equal to the last actioned date (without time), then the button should be disabled.  If the button has never been actioned, then it should be enabled. This leads you to the problem of determine if the actioned date/time is within the current day boundaries. You could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324633/nsdate-beginning-of-day-and-end-of-day) as a starting point

Comment: You could then check if the action date is within the current date/time bounds using something like `lastActionedDate.startOfDay...lastActionedDate.endOfDay ~= Date()` (remember, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324633/nsdate-beginning-of-day-and-end-of-day) for the `startOfDay` and `endOfDay` implementations) or, if you want to be sure it's after the actioned date, something like `Date() > lastActionedDate.endOfDay`

Comment: You need to use UserDefaults to store the date if this validation needs to be done after the app has been restarted as well.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I have now adjusted the function a little so that you can only click the button once a day. To do this, I save the date on which the button was clicked in the UserDefaults. When the app is opened, a timer runs, which executes a function every 60 seconds to check whether the current date is one day after the last saved date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset Bool value everyday at midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77689350/how-to-reset-bool-value-everyday-at-midnight)

Comment: @soundflix thank you for your reply. Please check my answer below, I used a similar approach.

Comment: You can subscribe to a notifications NSCalendarDayChanged, which fires when the calendar day changes. However, that is only a small part of the problem. Most iOS apps don't run continuously. They usually get suspended when the user switches apps or locks their device. Even Mac apps don't tend to be run continuously.

Comment: You should save the Date to UserDefaults when the user clicks the button, and when your app launches, check to see if a calendar day has passed, and re-enable the button if so. If not, subscribe to `NSCalendarDayChanged` notifications to cover the case where the calendar date changes while you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For documentation purposes**

I have now adjusted the function a little so that you can only click the button once a day. To do this, I save the date on which the button was clicked in the UserDefaults. When the app is opened, a timer runs, which executes a function every 60 seconds to check whether the current date is one day after the last saved date.

Code snippets:

```
@AppStorage("lastAppleDate") private var lastAppleDate: Date?

let timer = Timer.publish(every: 60, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

.onReceive(timer) { _ in
        checkIfButtonShouldBeEnabled()
    }

private func checkIfButtonShouldBeEnabled() {
    if let lastAppleDate = lastAppleDate {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        if !calendar.isDateInToday(lastAppleDate) {
            isButtonDisabled = false
        }
    } else {
        isButtonDisabled = false
    }
}
```